# Primefaces Datatable doesn't reset filter

Tags: primefaces, filter, datatable

I am facing some problems with filters in `DataTable` component in PrimeFaces ! 
I have a list of `Employees`to show in that table and of course I have the ability to seach some of them using :

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <div align="left">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('employee_Table').filter()"  placeholder="#{msg['SearchFields']} " />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </div>
</f:facet>
```

[image]

The problem is after typing a text in that `InputText` and clearing it to start modifyin an other employee I still get the same employee that I searched for or a list of employees if the search criteria matches with more than one !

Is there a way to reset the filters ?

Comment: Would you happen to call the DB in the getter-method that returns the list? I'm not totally getting it, does the problem exist if you don't click the edit-button (pencil) you've highlighted? Or is the list correct, but you get the wrong employee when clicking the pencil? Do you have a rowkey on the table?

Comment: I get the wrong employee when I click on the pencil yeah ! The filter results are still in the memory.
I found a solution and I'll put it as a response down ;) Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to clear the filters when the page got called ! Sometimes one single code line takes of you one day unfortunately

Under the `<p:form>` element I got to add this line :

```
<p:remoteCommand name="onload" oncomplete="PF('employee_Table').clearFilters()" autoRun="true" />
```

Here `employee_table` is the value of `widgetVar` of my `<p:datatable>` element.